# Why some websites are not automatable using Selenium chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I tried automating https://myaccount.payoneer.com/MainPage/SetAccount.aspx web page but couldn't figure out why website is not navigating to next page.

My script is opening page -> Entering user and password -> Clicking on Continue button but after click nothing shows up. While replicating the same steps manully works well. Is there any browser settings am I missing for these kind of sites? I am clueless

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Yongeei\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 5") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\hoc tool\\Day 2\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
w.get('https://myaccount.payoneer.com/MainPage/SetAccount.aspx')
time.sleep(5)
username = w.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('username')
time.sleep(1)
passw = w.find_element_by_name('password')
passw.send_keys('password')
passw.submit()
```

Comment: Were you able to proceed futher?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your steps in Java and it seems to submit, however I don't have an account so I could get to the next page anyway.

There are a few things I normally try around with this kind of form submission:

- password.submit();
- add a "\n" at the end of the password String. (or sendKeys(Keys.ENTER))
- click on the signIn button.
- if the last one doesn't work with the the normal click() function, try execute js script with your webdriver, `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('login_button').click()")`

Good luck!

Comment: account payoneer ngoquangpi77-1033@yahoo.com:Floyda552 can you help me ?